# Insert into new table an id with several values

Tags: sql

I've been struggling with this problem.

I have 2 populated tables and a third empty one and I would like to populate the third with data from the other two. Correlate values

The idea is to assign every single ID from the 1st table to entries (several) found in the 2nd table that respect the condition where DestinedUserTypeID should be equal to UserTypeID),

**Table 1**

| Id | UserName | UserTypeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bla | 1 |
| 2 | Ble | 2 |
| 3 | Bli | 3 |

**Table 2**

| ID | TaskName | DestinedUserTypeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task A | 1 |
| 2 | Task B | 1 |
| 3 | Task C | 1 |
| 4 | Task D | 2 |

**DESIRED TABLE, Table 3**

| ID | UserID | TaskID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

...

```html
Insert into Table3 ([UserId],[TaskID])
SELECT 
Id,
(SELECT [Id] FROM  [Table2] t2 
        WHERE [Id] <= 5 AND [DestinedUserTypeId] = 1) 
FROM t1 WHERE [UserTypeId] = 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd consider creating a view instead.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which database system do you want to use? Why not use a `JOIN`?

Comment: "Like this one" sounds like you want to share more details. Please do that in text form, unless this is really not possible

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry bad link. It's up now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple join linked to your table 1 and 2 and just insert into your table3

```
SELECT 
        u.id,
        t.id,
    from
        table1 as u inner join
        table2 as t on u.userTypeId = t.DestinedUserTypeID
```